# sample(letters[1:4]) then rename data in R

Tags: r

I have created a basic statistics experiment where I have used random sampling for the treat variable which results in a column containing d, b, a, c, a, d, b, c ... etc (R code copied below). 
I have now been told instead of listing d, b, a, c, I need to list the names so apple instead of a, banana instead of b, carrot instead of c and durian for d. I'm having trouble finding information about how to do this. Could someone please help?

```
> block=rep(1:8,rep(4,8))
> treat=factor(c(sample(letters[1:4])))
> variable1=Data[order(Data$variable1),]
> Animals=data.frame(variable1,block=factor(block),treat=factor(treat)) 
> Animals
```

Comment: what's your Data? can't recreate your problem without it

Comment: Can't you just replace your second line of code with: `treat=factor(sample(c("apple","banana","carrot","durian")))`

Comment: No, I had tried that but it just lists "carrot, apple, banana, durian, carrot, apple, banana, durian...." over and over in the exact same order. It must be randomized otherwise carrot is always assigned the smaller values from variable1 (which is ordered numerically from small to large).

Comment: you could do what @jlhoward suggested.  and to randomize it use `sample(treat, length(variable1), replace =T)`

Answer (score 0):

So in your code, `block` is a vector of length 32, `treat` is a vector of length 4, and `variable1` is a vector of unknown length because you don't tell us anything about `Data`.

If you combine them into a data frame, and assuming `variable1` is at least as long as `block`, you will *replicate* `block` and `treat` as many times as necessary to match the length of `variable1`. So `treat` will be *replicated* at least 8 times (to fill out `block`).

If you want a randomized block design (do you??), where all four treats appear in each block, in random order, then you need to use something like this

```
treats    <- c("apple","banana","carrot","durian")
n.blocks  <- 8
block     <- rep(1:n.blocks,rep(length(treats),n.blocks))
treat     <- as.vector(sapply(1:n.blocks,function(i)sample(treats)))
variable1 <- Data[order(Data$variable1),]
Animals   <- data.frame(variable1,block=factor(block),treat=factor(treat))
```

The line

```
treat     <- as.vector(sapply(1:n.blocks,function(i)sample(treats)))
```

will call `sample(...)` 8 times, each returning all 4 treats in a (different) random order, and then combine the results into a single vector of length 32.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
ifelse(treat=="a", "apple", ifelse(treat=="b","banana", ifelse(treat=="c","carrot","durian")))
```

`ifelse` takes 3 arguements. Test, value for True, value for False.
I just nested them to change your variables.

to assign the output of the code above do this:
    treat.newlabels <- ifelse(treat=="a", "apple", ifelse(treat=="b","banana", ifelse(treat=="c","carrot","durian")))

and use treat.newlabels in your analysis. You can name it whatever you want. You can even assign it back to treat, but this is safer and clearer

Comment: Sorry, I added that line of code which R accepts and writes: [1] "banana" "durian" "apple"  "carrot" under it but then my data output is treat: b d a c b d a c, so its just taking the above order (banana, durian, apple, carrot) and listing them in that order as letters again. How do I attach my raw data for you to view?

Comment: do `dput(data)`,  where data is your data.frame, copy the output of that and paste it on SO (stackoverflow)

Comment: That's not a very good way to do it if you're going to take this approach.  There is a lot of boilerplate there.  `treat <- c("a", "b", "b"); dict <- c("a" = "apple", "b" = "banana"); dict[treat]`